# calling objective c method from callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording

first of all I am newbie! 
I am trying to get audio data from microphone and apply filter. the filter I found is an objective c methods based NVDSP filter. the filter method and the callback function coming from microphone is down below. But I dont know how to connect the dots. how can I call objective c method which is FilterData from the performRender callback?

```
static OSStatus performRender (void                     *inRefCon,
                           AudioUnitRenderActionFlags   *ioActionFlags,
                           const AudioTimeStamp         *inTimeStamp,
                           UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                           UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                           AudioBufferList              *ioData)
{
    UInt32 bus1 = 1;
    CheckError(AudioUnitRender(effectState.rioUnit,
                           ioActionFlags,
                           inTimeStamp,
                           bus1,
                           inNumberFrames,
                           ioData), "Couldn't render from RemoteIO unit");


//how can I call the method here to apply filter on ioData->mBuffers[0].mData ? 
//is this logical ? what should I do for best performance?


    return noErr;
}



@implementation ViewController

...
...
-(float *) FilterData_rawSamples:(float *)samples
{
    // setup Highpass filter
    NVHighpassFilter *HPF;
    HPF = [[NVHighpassFilter alloc] initWithSamplingRate:samplingRate];

    HPF.cornerFrequency = 17500.0f;
    HPF.Q = 0.5f;

    [HPF filterData:samples numFrames:(UInt32)theFileLengthInFrames numChannels:1];
    return samples;
}
...
...

@end
```

thanksin advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the code where you're hooking the callback into the data source (microphone API?).

Typically at that point you will pass in an object.  I'm noticing a parameter to the callback:

```
void                     *inRefCon
```

Which you aren't using.  Take a look at the documentation - likely you're able to pass in your objective-c object and the callback will make it accessible through a parameter.  inRefCon sounds vaguely like it might be the parameter you're looking for.

Correctly pass in your object, then cast inRefCon in the callback.  (again please look at the docs for whatever API call you're making, it might outline this, I'm guessing).

Comment: here is the code that is hooked to callback function
// Set the render callback on AURemoteIO
    AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
    renderCallback.inputProc = performRender;
    renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
so as you said I put the self into the inRefCon variable.

Comment: Cool - So to finish you'll do something like  MyCoolType * object = (__bridge MyCoolType * )inRefCon;  [object callMyMethod];  Done!

Answer (score 2):

here is the code that hooks up the callback function

```
// Set the render callback on AURemoteIO
AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
renderCallback.inputProc = performRender;
renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
```

so I send self to the inRefCon according to Kirk's post then I use it like this

```
ViewController *vc = (__bridge ViewController *) inRefCon;
float * filteredData = [vc FilterData_rawSamples:ioData->mBuffers[0].mData numSamples:inNumberFrames ];
//by the way I changed the filterData method
```

thanks Kirk